# ngb-carousel width not becoming 100%

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

[I am using ngb-carousel but i am unable to put width 100% as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcQYJ.png)

## Html Code for reference

```
<ngb-carousel
  #carousel
  [interval]="10000"
  [pauseOnHover]="pauseOnHover"
  [pauseOnFocus]="pauseOnFocus"
  (slide)="onSlide($event)">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let img of images; index as i">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>My slide {{i + 1}} title</h3>
    </div>
    <a
      href="https://www.google.fr/?q=Number+{{i+1}}"
      target="_blank"
      rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="img" alt="My image {{i + 1}} description" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

I want to make the ngb-carousel 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Try adding globally (eg. in `styles.scss`):

```css
ngb-carousel .picsum-img-wrapper > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or in component styles:

```css
.picsum-img-wrapper > img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```